# Java: Create text window to display console text

Tags: java, console, jconsole

I'm looking to create a seperate window in my java program to basically display the things that I print using println(). It would be nice to have some way of making certain text read and/or bold if it starts with "error:". Is there an easy or straight forward way to doing this?

Comment: Are you asking how to change the text's color?

Comment: Sorry, must have worded it wrong. That's just a side issue that I would like, what I ultimately want to know is how to make a separate window that would display everything I'm printing to the console. This way the people using my program will see everything I'm printing when they are running it outside of the ide.

Comment: Ok, see my answer below.

Comment: What specifically is your problem? Are you asking how to create a window? Are you asking how to add a text area to a window? Or are you specifically asking about how to do the stdout/stderr redirection?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to write a function that takes a `String` as an argument and then 1) prints to console using `System.out.print*()`, followed by printing or copying over text to that window's `JTextField`, or a constructor, or whatever method you are using to print text in that window, i.e.:

```
public method printAndCopyText(String text) {
   System.out.println(text);
   otherWindowObject.getTextFieldObject().setText(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PipedInputStream;
import java.io.PipedOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class JConsole {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JConsole");
        JTextPane jta = new JTextPane();
        JButton button = new JButton("Run");
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(button,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(jta,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new SwingWorker<Void, Object>(){
                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                        outputTest("inner");
                        return null;
                    }}.execute();
            }});

        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        console(jta);
    }

    public static void outputTest(String msg){
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            System.out.println(i+" "+msg);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void console(final JTextPane area) throws IOException {
        area.setContentType("text/html");
        final PipedInputStream outPipe = new PipedInputStream();
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(new PipedOutputStream(outPipe), true));       
        new SwingWorker<Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                Scanner s = new Scanner(outPipe);
                while (s.hasNextLine()){
                    String line = s.nextLine();
                    publish(line + "\n");
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
                for (String line : chunks){
                    area.setText("<font size=\"3\" color=\"red\">"+line+"</font>");
                }
            }
        }.execute();
    }

}
```